# Reading OBS PBF files using C#

Tags: c#, openstreetmap, osm.pbf

I have downloaded a `.osm.pbf` file from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html and
need to convert the data (streets etc) to Graphs so I can calculate routes. I believe these files already work with **Nodes**, but have trouble reading the data.

I tried using https://www.osmsharp.com/ but don't really understand the software.

Can someone give me links to a proper library or give me a few tips in how to access the data from the OSM. Some pseudo / example code is fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to play around with [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) first to get an idea about how OSM data works. It is also very helpful to launch an OSM editor (e.g. the browser editor [iD](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ID) or the standalone editor [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/)) to take a look at real OSM data.

Later you can read about the [PBF format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format#Software_support_for_PBF) (it is mainly smaller and faster than OSM XML) and about [PBF software support](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF/Software_Compliance). Use one of the existing libraries, don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Also read about how to [calculate a routing graph from OSM data](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/19213/how-can-i-convert-an-osm-xml-file-into-a-graph-representation). Also look at [routing](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) in the OSM wiki. There is some general information available as well as a list of online and offline routers. If you are stuck you can take a look at their implementations.